# java- where does a pointer points to if I dont declare it to null

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

When I doing this question on leetcode:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        Stack s = new Stack();

    ListNode curr = head;
    while (curr != null) {
        s.push(curr);
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    ListNode newHead = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode track = newHead;
    while (!s.empty()) {
        track.next =(ListNode) (s.pop());
        track = track.next;
    }
    track.next = null;

    return newHead.next;
    }
}
```

If I don't have `track.next = null`, then the code will run wrong. So what will track. Next points to if I do not declare it pointing to `null`?

Comment: "the code will run wrong"  - what does that mean?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `track.next = null` is not a *declaration*. It's an *assignment*, so if you remove it, the value is unmodified, i.e. retains the value it already has. Since `track` is the new "last" node, it used to be the "first" node, which used to point to the "second" node, so if left unmodified, it will still point to what used to be the "second" node, which is now the "second-last" node, thereby creating a loop between the last two nodes. Simple **debugging** would have shown you that, so ... http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're giving `track.next` the original node's reference, which already has an assigned `next` value. Follow the logic on this example:

Say you have ListNode of size 3, using node 1 as the root:

`( 1 ) --> ( 2 ) --> ( 3 ) --> null`

In your implementation, you take each node and add it to the stack, like so:

Node   -->   `next`

```
|  3      null |  <--- Top of stack
|  2        3  |
|  1        2  |
```

Then you make a new node `newHead` and start popping nodes off the stack, assigning the values to your node like so:

```
( 3 )  -->  ( 2 )  -->  ( 1 ) --> ( 2 )
```

Since you haven't updated the `track.next` value for the original head of the list, it's still pointing to node 2. But node 2 now points to node 1, so you're caught in an infinite loop. By calling `track.next = null` at the end, you're changing the above to look like so:

```
( 3 ) --> ( 2 ) --> ( 1 ) --> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are reversing a Linked List. 
Let's say list be  a-> b-> c

You put them in stash.
Now you pop them in reverse and setting the pointer.

So, c->b->a (---> this is old value of a's pointer which point to b)

We need c->b->a->null

That's why `track.next = null;` is required.

What if we don't use it ?

Then the linked list formed by reversing will be

c -> b -> a

```
   | ___|  (a pointing back to b)
```

That's why any other code which access such reversed linked list will malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, u are reversing a linked list by first pushing elements on to stack starting from its head, and then popping the elements from the stack ,to recreate the links in reverse order. The last node of reversed list will be the first node of the original list. SO set the tail of reversed list to null.

```
    ListNode newHead = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode track = newHead;
    while (!s.empty()) {
        track.next =(ListNode) (s.pop());
        track = track.next;
    }
    #track is now pointing to the head (that was the first one pushed on to stack).
    track.next = null; # set the tail of reversed list to null.
```